# Is Anyone/ Who is used together?

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

> The course is for anyone who is interested in learning about computers.

Is there an error in the above sentence formation?

Or can we just say:

> The course is for anyone interested in learning about computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just say *The course is for anyone interested in learning about computers*, but you can also place *who is* between *anyone* and *interested*.

Comment: I hope it helps.